# Force uniqueness in JSONB array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, unique, jsonb

Let's say I have a table `students` with a column type `jsonb` where I store a list with students' additional emails. A student row looks like this

| student_id | name | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | [j.doe@email.com] |

I'm using the following query to update the `emails` column:

```
UPDATE students SET emails = emails || '["j.doe@email.com"]'::jsonb
                     WHERE student_id=1
                     AND NOT emails @> '["j.doe@email.com"]'::jsonb;
```

Once the column `emails` is filled, if I reuse query above with the parameter `["j.doe@email.com", "john@email.com"]`, the column `emails` would be update with repeated value:

| student_id | name | emails |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Student 1 | [j.doe@email.com, j.doe@email.com, john@email.com] |

Is there a way to make sure that in the column `emails` I'll always have a jsonb list with only unique values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this handy function which removes duplicates from a jsonb array:

```sql
create or replace function jsonb_unique_array(jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql immutable as $$
    select jsonb_agg(distinct value)
    from jsonb_array_elements($1) 
$$;
```

Your update statement may look like this:

```sql
update students 
set emails = jsonb_unique_array(emails || '["j.doe@email.com", "john@email.com"]'::jsonb)
where student_id=1
and not emails @> '["j.doe@email.com", "john@email.com"]'::jsonb
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f01ed81a1ffc739e8918570588e674d1)

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks!